# Owin authentication cookie not visible subsequent to the first request

Tags: authentication, owin

MVC 5 app with Microsoft Owin v3 authenticating users via Windows Azure Active Directory. I have a login process that I don't fully understand. I expect to see a cookie on every request by I only see one on the landing page after sign-in. After navigating to another controller the cookie disappears yet the session appears to be authenticated correctly. Does anyone know how this is working? Here is my sign on logic...I don't see any cookie with the expiry time set in any browser. I see .AspNet.Cookies, __RequestVerificationToken and 2 cookies associated with a support utility. Removing any of these using Firebug has no effect on the user session and I remain logged in.

```
HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/", IsPersistent = true, AllowRefresh = true, ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(20) }, 
                OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType
            );
```

And here is the startup logic taken from an online example...

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        //TODO: Use the Ioc container to get this but need to check if the kernel has been created before this runs
        string applicationClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get(ConfigurationConstants.AppSettings.AzureApplicationClientId);

        //fixed address for multitenant apps in the public cloud
        string authority = "https://login.windows.net/common/";

        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions { CookieDomain = "example.com" });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = applicationClientId,
                Authority = authority,
                TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    // instead of using the default validation (validating against a single issuer value, as we do in line of business apps), 
                    // we inject our own multitenant validation logic
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                },
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                {

                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
                    {
                        // This ensures that the address used for sign in and sign out is picked up dynamically from the request
                        // this allows you to deploy your app (to Azure Web Sites, for example)without having to change settings
                        // Remember that the base URL of the address used here must be provisioned in Azure AD beforehand.
                        string appBaseUrl = context.Request.Scheme + "://" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.PathBase;
                        context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = appBaseUrl;
                        //This will need changing to the web site home page once it is live
                        context.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = "http://www.example.com";
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                    // we use this notification for injecting our custom logic
                    SecurityTokenValidated = (context) =>
                    {
                        // retriever caller data from the incoming principal
                        string issuer = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("iss").Value;
                        string UPN = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value;
                        string tenantId = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;

                        //Todo - fetch the tenant info

                        //if ((db.Tenants.FirstOrDefault(a => ((a.IdentityProvider == issuer) && (a.ActiveDirectoryTenantId == tenantId))) == null))
                        //    // the caller wasn't from a trusted issuer throw to block the authentication flow
                        //    throw new SecurityTokenValidationException();
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                    AuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                    {
                        context.OwinContext.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error");
                        context.HandleResponse(); // Suppress the exception
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }
            });

    }
```